# How to make sure microcontrollers peripheral register has been read

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

Let's take STM32F205 microcontroller for example. It has hardware SPI interface. SPI consists of several register. A received byte is stored in the data register SPI->DR. And when new byte has been received the RXNE flag (Rx not empy) is set in the SPI status register SPI->SR by the hardware. The proper way to clear this flag is to read out a content of the data register SPI->DR. If I use temporary variable it may be optimized away (because it is not used):

```
uint8_t foo = SPI1->DR;
```

I saw another unusual thing in embedded software but I'm not sure whether it's correct:

```
(void)SPI1->DR;
```

So I'm looking for the way how to make sure the data register has been read eaven at high optimization level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [volatile](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472c/CJAEGDEA.html) keyword to prevent unwanted optimization.

```
volatile uint8_t foo = SPI1->DR;
```

To avoid compiler warnings you can do the following

```
(void)foo;
```

Comment: In this case I'll get an unwanted compiler's warning (foo was asigned value but not used).

Comment: Actually I don't need the value of the data rigister. I have to read it in order to make the hardware clear the RXNE flag. Assigning its value to a variable is just a simplest way.

Comment: How about `(void)SPI1->DR;`, without temporary variable? Will it work the same way?

Comment: I don't know. It depens. You should look how `SPI1->DR` is declared in the header file. If it uses the volatile keyword it works as well.

Comment: @Max Don't rely on `(void)SPI1->DR;` generating any instructions even though DR is defined as volatile. This is a typical case where compilers tend to behave incorrectly and optimize the code away.

Comment: Your compiler should not issue an "unused" warning for an unused `volatile`.

Answer (score 2):

All hardware registers in header files are declared volatile, so the reads will *NEVER* be optimized away. The construct you showed - `(void)SPI1->DR;` (the `(void)` part is actually redundant) is just that - a read operation that will not be optimized, so you're safe to use that and that's the best option - there are no useless temporary variables needed. This is similar to stuff you sometimes see like `(void)0;`.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to put the read in a separately compiled file.  one file has a function with the read that returns the value read, cant optimize that out, has to do it.  Another file calls that function but doesnt use the return value, cant optimize that out.  you have the cost of the function call which is fairly cheap in this case, but until you do something like optimize the entire project with llvm or something like that it cant optimize the read away.

Another solution is to use assembly language make a simple ldr r0,[r0], bx lr function, pass it the address.  as above because it is in a separate compile/optimization domain it cannot be optimized out.

Answer (score 0):

Typically SPI rx status flags are cleared by two reads: you read the data register but you also need to read the status register to know the actual status. Since the read to the data register clears the flags, you will need to read the status register first.

To insure that there is misbehaviour and no incorrect code generated, I would strongly advise to place the read of status and data registers next to each other in the code.

To avoid the code getting optimized away, use local variables declared as volatile.

```
volatile uint8_t sr = SRI1->SR;
volatile uint8_t dr = SPI1->DR;

// do stuff with sr and dr

(void) dr; // if not interested in the received data
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not be optimised away because SPI1->DR should be declared `volatile`.